# Which actions can I do in implemented methods?

Tags: java

I want to simulate shots fired. The gun has 6 bullets. After each shot the number of bullets should decrease.

Here's the code

```
public interface Gun {
  public void shot();
  public void reload();
}
```

And here's main:

```
package com.example;

class HelloCodiva {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pistol pistol = new Pistol();
    Gun gun;
    gun = new Pistol();
    gun.shot();
    System.out.println(pistol.getBullets());
    gun.shot();
    gun.shot();
  }
}
```

```
class Pistol implements Gun {
  private int bullets;
  private int damage;
  private boolean reload;

  public Pistol () {
    this.bullets = 6;
    this.damage = 10;
  }

  @Override
  public void shot() {
      this.bullets-=1;
      System.out.println("Shotting");
  }

  @Override
  public void reload() {
      if(reload){
      System.out.println("Reloading...");
        reload = false;
      }

  }

  public int getBullets() {
    return bullets;
  }

}
```

But I always get the same initial amount (6). What I do wrong?

Comment: Do you create new `Pistol` instance every time? `bullets` will be set to 6.

Comment: where do you create `Pistol`, where do you call `shot()` on it? Where do you output the result of `getBullets()`?

Comment: Yes, actually I do...(creating new instance) damn is this a root of the problem?

Comment: I tried your code and it works without any problem

Comment: How do you use that code? What is the purpose of `reload` filed? Why `reload()` method doesn't modify amount of `bullets` in gun?

Comment: BTW I would change Gun from Interface to abstract class. You create interface to set a contract between any interface or class but you create an abstract class to create a class which will act as a superclass to many different classes while you not wanting its instance to be created.

Comment: In your edit, you are shooting `gun` but printing `pistol` bullets, this is where the problem is

Comment: Cuz first I want bullets to decrease and then already do some actions with reload. I added what I'm doing at the main

Comment: Oh thx about abstracts, I'll change that. Atm I'm trying to get the idea of interface (cuz still can't find where can I use that).

Answer (score 0):

You are shooting from

```
Gun gun;
    gun = new Pistol();
```

But counting the bullet from

```
Pistol pistol = new Pistol();
 System.out.println(pistol.getBullets());
```